# joblib.dump() fails when saving model to temporary data store in AMLS

Tags: python, joblib, azure-machine-learning-service

I am training a model using AMLS. I have a training pipeline in which step 1 trains a model then saves the output in temporary datastore model_folder using

```
os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)
output_path = output_folder + "/model.pkl"
joblib.dump(value=model, filename=output_path)
```

Step 2 loads the model and registers it. The model folder is defined in the pipeline as

```
model_folder = PipelineData("model_folder", datastore=ws.get_default_datastore())
```

However, step 1 fails when it tries to save the model with the following ServiceError:

Failed to upload outputs due to Exception: Microsoft.RelInfra.Common.Exceptions.OperationFailedException: Cannot upload output xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx. ---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

How can I solve this? Earlier in my code I had no problem interacting with the default datastore using

```
default_ds = ws.get_default_datastore()
default_ds.upload_files(...)
```

My `70_driver_log.txt` is as follows:

```
[2020-08-25T04:03:27.315114] Entering context manager injector.
[context_manager_injector.py] Command line Options: Namespace(inject=['ProjectPythonPath:context_managers.ProjectPythonPath', 'RunHistory:context_managers.RunHistory', 'TrackUserError:context_managers.TrackUserError'], invocation=['train_word2vec.py', '--output_folder', '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/aiworkspace/azureml/xxxxx/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/xxxxx/model_folder', '--model_type', 'WO', '--training_field', 'task_title', '--regex', '1', '--stopword_removal', '1', '--tokenize_basic', '0', '--remove_punctuation', '0', '--autocorrect', '0', '--lemmatization', '1', '--word_vector_length', '152', '--model_learning_rate', '0.025', '--model_min_count', '0', '--model_window', '7', '--num_epochs', '10'])
Starting the daemon thread to refresh tokens in background for process with pid = 113
Entering Run History Context Manager.
Current directory:  /mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/aiworkspace/azureml/xxxxx/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/xxxxx
Preparing to call script [ train_word2vec.py ] with arguments: ['--output_folder', '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/aiworkspace/azureml/xxxxx/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/xxxxx/model_folder', '--model_type', 'WO', '--training_field', 'task_title', '--regex', '1', '--stopword_removal', '1', '--tokenize_basic', '0', '--remove_punctuation', '0', '--autocorrect', '0', '--lemmatization', '1', '--word_vector_length', '152', '--model_learning_rate', '0.025', '--model_min_count', '0', '--model_window', '7', '--num_epochs', '10']
After variable expansion, calling script [ train_word2vec.py ] with arguments: ['--output_folder', '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/aiworkspace/azureml/xxxxx/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/xxxxx/model_folder', '--model_type', 'WO', '--training_field', 'task_title', '--regex', '1', '--stopword_removal', '1', '--tokenize_basic', '0', '--remove_punctuation', '0', '--autocorrect', '0', '--lemmatization', '1', '--word_vector_length', '152', '--model_learning_rate', '0.025', '--model_min_count', '0', '--model_window', '7', '--num_epochs', '10']

Script type = None
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to /root/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping corpora/stopwords.zip.
[nltk_data] Downloading package wordnet to /root/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping corpora/wordnet.zip.
OUTPUT FOLDER: /mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/aiworkspace/azureml/xxxxx/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/xxxxx/model_folder
Loading SQL data...
Loading abbreviation data...
/azureml-envs/azureml_xxxxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1783: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self.obj[item_labels[indexer[info_axis]]] = value
Pre-processing data...
Succesfully pre-processed the the text data
Training Word2Vec model...
Saving the model...
Starting the daemon thread to refresh tokens in background for process with pid = 113


The experiment completed successfully. Finalizing run...
[2020-08-25T04:03:52.293994] TimeoutHandler __init__
[2020-08-25T04:03:52.294149] TimeoutHandler __enter__
Cleaning up all outstanding Run operations, waiting 300.0 seconds
2 items cleaning up...
Cleanup took 0.44109439849853516 seconds
[2020-08-25T04:03:52.818991] TimeoutHandler __exit__
2020/08/25 04:04:00 logger.go:293: Process Exiting with Code:  0
```

My arg parse arguments include

```
parser.add_argument('--output_folder', type=str, dest='output_folder', default="output_folder", help='output folder')
```

Comment: it's in the error. looks like a permission issue

Comment: have you successfully written to a `PipelineData` in a `PythonScriptStep` before? can you share the full stacktrack from the `70_driver_log.txt`? Can you also add your arg parse arguments?

Comment: Yes, I've successfully written this type of code before. It worked on my subscription, but does not work when I try it on a different subscription. 70_driver_log.txt does not contain the error I mentioned, but will add it to my original post.

Comment: Actually I get the same error when I try to save the model locally, so it might not be a PipelineData issue. Do I need to have an enterprise subscription to do this?

Comment: No you shouldn’t need the SDK to save the model locally...

Comment: Yes I agree, and I have no problem saving the model locally in general, but when I try to do it from my training script, I get the same permission error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this problem by adding my AMLS workspace to a 'storage blob data contributor' role in the AMLS default storage account. It seemly like usually this role is added by default, but it didn't happen in my case.

Answer (score 0):

some ideas:

1. It is as @drum suggests and is a permission error.
2. Your `ArgumentParser` has a minor typo
3. Does the same error occur if you use `os.path.join(output_folder, 'model.pkl')`?